# BreezeJS - Error When Querying Model with Entities at Multiple Depths

Tags: breeze

My model looks looks like this:

```
Project
Project.Tags
Project.Sheets

Sheet
Sheet.Tags

Tag
Tag.Sheets
Tag.Project
```

I am querying a single Project and expanding ("Sheets, Tags, Sheets.Tags").  The query always fails with TypeError: undefined is not a function.

The error goes away if I don't expand Sheets.Tags or if I remove the Tags collection from the Project object.

When I downgrade to breeze 1.3.4, it gives the Error: Nonscalar navigation properties are readonly - entites can be added or removed but the collection may not be changed.

Is there a way to accomplish what I want without having to make separate server calls?

Comment: I see you edited your post, but to give a better idea of what you may be doing wrong it would be very useful to see the query and also make sure your foreign keys are set up properly.

Comment: I just found that breeze does not yet support many to many relationships; I'm pretty confident that this is causing the issue.  It would be nice if you added this to your article that describes how you configured EF.

Comment: I don't have an article, not entirely sure what you are talking about : )

Comment: My bad; I was referring to [this article](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/server-side-model-0) ... don't know why I assumed it was yours.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had this problem. Interestingly, after you get project.tags back from breeze, if you refer to project.tagsList in your binding (I use Angular), then you get no error. Breeze doesn't seem to like it if you use the exact navigation property naming.